# how can i know if i am using specman 64/32 bit during runtime

Tags: specman

I want to write some e code that is conditioned by the used specman architecture (64/32 bit).

What i need will look like:

```
if (specman 64 bit) {
                       do something 
                    } else {
                      do something else 
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

One can do so, by using the predefinef SN_64_BIT define.

I.e , one can condition the appearance of code by this define, for example:

```
<'
extend sys {

run() is also{

    #ifdef SN_64_BIT then 
      {   out("64 bit"); }
      #else 
      { out("32 bit "); }

    };

  };
'>
```